# Adding qualifier to objectProperty in OWL

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology

I want to express the following in an OWL ontology in Protege: IndividualA is composed of IndividualB1 at X %, IndividualB2 at Y % and so on, up until 100%.

Does a pattern exists to model this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to express the following in an OWL ontology in Protege:
>   IndividualA is composed of IndividualB1 at X %, IndividualB2 at Y %
>   and so on, up until 100%.
>
> Does a pattern exists to model this?

I don't think you'll be able to get the guarantee/restriction on sums that you're looking for in OWL.  But part of the structure that you're talking about is just an n-ary relationship.  Instead of a two place relationship

**isComposedOf(IndividualA, IndividualB1)**

you have a three place relationship:

**isComposedOfByPercent(IndividualA, IndividualB1, 0.34)**

There are lots of ways to represent n-ary relationships using semantic technologies, so many so that the W3C published a working note, [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).  In OWL, one of the most common approaches might be:

```
x a Composition ;
  hasComposite IndividualA ;
  hasComponent IndividualB1 ;
  hasPercentage 0.34 .
```

Another might be:

```
IndividualA hasCompositePart y .
y a CompositePart ;
  hasComponent IndividualB1 ;
  hasPercentage 0.34 .
```

Comment: I had thought about the second but it seemed not very "semantic" to me, since we're defining an individual that has no meaning on its own, in my opinion. The one with the "Composition" class seems better to me, I'll go with it. Many thanks.

Comment: @SimoneS93 In both cases there's a new individual;  in the first, it's **x**, in the second it's **y**. Which I'd prefer might depend on the application;  in this case, we'd probably be more interested in the parts that IndividualA has, so I might prefer the second, but in some cases I'd prefer the first.  But even so, both cases require four triples, and you end up with a new "meaningless" individual.  That's just part of what ends up happening when your fundamental building block is a labeled directed edge.